# Where should I put SQL queries in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the best practice where should I put SQL queries in Rails?

- Should I create the methods in models for example: find_all_public_items where I'm using the find methods with all the conditions, and then using them in controllers. Like that I have all the queries in one place but I miss the flexibility that every query should be exactly suited for the need.
- Should I just use the find/find_by_sql in controllers - like this I'm not creating thousands of methods but i'm loosing control on how the controllers are sucking data from database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should put them in your models. You might want to investigate [named scopes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/108-named-scope) too.

Comment: That named scopes mechanism looks pretty cool:  short and sweet macro-ish thing to generate the queries given just a hint at the "where" clause for the need of the day.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, I like the fact that you pointed out something to make it easier, rather than simply saying "thou shalt" (implied:  even if it hurts, etc)

Comment: Named scopes are particularly nice because you can chain them together.

Answer (score 8):

Put everything model-related in the model. Period.